# On / after learning the news he left for home

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

As a basic learner I have confusions between these sentences:

> **On** learning the news he left for home.
>
> **After** learning the news he left for home.
>
> Learning the news he left for home.

The **1** and **3** , to me, seems to convey that there is no time- gap between the two actions.
Am I right?

Are they interchange?

Thank you.

Comment: Also ***Upon** learning the news he left for home*, which even more strongly implies ***immediate*** reaction.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence pretty clearly implies, at least in the absence of any context to the contrary, that he left for home **promptly** on learning the news. The third sentence suggests the same, but less strongly. The middle sentence is more ambiguous.  "After learning the news" could well mean **immediately** after. But it might not. With no additional context, I would conclude that it did mean  immediately after. But I would not feel as confident of that conclusion.

So the three sentences are not **quite** interchangeable, standing alone.  But with additional context, any of them might be used in the same situation. Each of them is grammatical. Personally I would avoid the final sentence, but that is a matter of style, not grammar.

(By the way, that is "interchangeable", not "interchange".)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with your intuition that "On" indicates that he left for home immediately.

Typically I would understand "After" to mean the same thing, though there is potentially some ambiguity depending on context. You could remedy this by adding "immediately":

> **Immediately** after learning the news, he left for home.

Or in the other direction:

> Quite a bit after learning the news, he left for home.

I agree with David's preference against the third sentence, though it's possible that it's just a regional thing.